# Extract a value property from either an array OR object using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, aws-lambda, webhooks

I have some options in a dropdown box on my website which are then sent via webhook for me to extract details from. I am trying to extract the *value* from the ageId object.

But depending on the dropdown item selected, it is either placed into an array or an object with some other details added.

[image: Age Dropdown]

When the **Adult** option is chosen, ageId is:
`[ { i: 0, value: '25', label: 'Adult' } ]`

When the **Senior** option is chosen, ageId is:
`{ '1': { i: 1, value: '65', label: 'Senior' } }`

Before I added more dropdown options, the following worked to extract the required property of **25**

```
const ageMinimum = event.ageId[0].value[Object.keys(event.ageId[0].value)[0]].value;
```

How can I extract the *value* (eg.25 or 65) property every time regardless of the dropdown selected and the subsequent changing syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
var adult = [ { i: 0, value: '25', label: 'Adult' } ];
var senior = { '1': { i: 1, value: '65', label: 'Senior' } };
var tmp = senior; // Or adult

var ageMinimum  = (Array.isArray(tmp) ? tmp[0] : tmp[Object.keys(tmp)[0]]).value; // Edited to work with flexible first object property names
console.log(ageMinimum);
```

Comment: So the object that comes through is called ageId that contains the info: value, i and labels etc. So the next option for say a *Student* would be ```{ '2': { i: 2, value: '18', label: 'Student' } };``` - So would it just be case of replacing your ```tmp``` references with ```AgeId```?

Comment: I modified the line that accesses the object to not depend on a fixed object property name

Comment: Please check here for a working example: https://jsbin.com/nomitalipi/edit?html,js,output